# xsltproc indentation doesn't work when using xsl:include or xsl:import

Tags: xslt

I have two templates - List.xsl and Main.xsl. Main.xsl is included in List.xsl with xsl:include. When List.xsl is transformed with xsltproc, all the code it generates doesn't have any indentation, though if the same code is placed in Main.xsl instead of `<xsl:apply-templates />` between body tags, indentation works. Also indentation works OK with Saxon in both case. Is it bug of xsltproc?

List.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-datatypes"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:include href="Main.xsl" />

  ...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Main.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
    method="xml"
    encoding="utf-8"
    indent="yes"
    cdata-section-elements="script style" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> List </title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example of output in first case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title> List </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body><dl class="list"><dt>Term</dt><dd><ul><li> ... </li></ul></dd></dl></body>
</html>
```

Example of output in second case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title> List </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <dl class="list">
      <dt>Term</dt>
      <dd>
        <ul>
          <li> ... </li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If List.xsl has an `xsl:output` element, its values take priority over those specified in the imported stylesheet.  For output properties not specified in List.xsl, the values specified in the imported Main.xsl should apply.  If List.xsl does not have any `xsl:output` element with `indent="yes"`, then yes, this appears to be a bug in libxslt.

Comment: I already forgot about this question and I'm not able to reproduce this problem now. Maybe it was because of `xsl:output` element priority. I didn't know that, thank You!

Comment: Interestingly, the `indent="yes"` seems to be partially ignored if `xsltproc` is used with `--html` option. Partially means that only the xml nodes explicitly specified in the xsl-template are indented. The HTML elements keep the indentation from the original html file.